# GrayScale Image Flip in c or c++?

Tags: c++, c, image, grayscale

I am trying to flip a gray scale image horizontally. Pointer fp is pointing to original image and pointer fp1 is creating horizontally flipped image. The Program is executing properly but the output image is worst...

```
    for( i =0 ;i<width ; i++)
     for(j=0; j <height; j++)
              idata[i][height - 1 -j] = ( (unsigned char)fgetc(fp));
    //flipping image          
for( i =0 ;i<width ; i++)
     for(j=0; j <height; j++)
              putc(idata[i][j] , fp1);
```

there is no problem in header copy of image. i think problem is residing in for loop... plz help me out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you are not mixing up width and height? The code seems to assume that the data is read in a column wise order when it most likely is in a row wise order. Try flipping the for loops and the dimension for flipping, like so:

```
for(j = 0; j < height; j++)
    for(i = 0; i < width; i++)
        idata[width - 1 - i][j] = ( (unsigned char)fgetc(fp));

//flipping image          

for(j = 0; j < height; j++)
    for(i = 0; i < width; i++)
        putc(idata[i][j] , fp1);
```